# Wix : get msi property from bundle command line

Tags: wix

I want to set a regitry value from my bundle command line. But can not get my variable in my product msi.

```
>bundle.exe defaultserver=www.google.com


<Bundle Name="MyBundle" ...>
  <WixVarible Id=DefaultServerValue" Value="" bal:Overridable=yes"/>
  <MsiPackage Id="MsiPkg1" ...>
    <MsiProperty Name="DEFAULTURLSERVER" Value=[DefaultServerValue]/>
  </MsiPackage>
</Bundle>

<Product>
 <Propety Id="DEFAULTURLSERVER" Value="Unknown"/>
 ...
 <Component Id="RegistryDefaultServer64" Win64="yes">
        <RegistryKey ForceCreateOnInstall="yes" ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\myPRoduct" Root="HKLM">
          <RegistryValue Name="DefaultServer" Type="string" KeyPath="yes" Value="[DEFAULTURLSERVER]>/
        </RegistryKey>
      </Component>
</Product>
```

My Bootstrapper application is allright, it the logs i have the following command line:

```
>Myproduct.msi DEFAULTURLSERVER="www.google.fr"
```

At the execution my registry value is created but it's empty.
Can you help me?

Comment: In your msi mark the DEFAULTURLSERVER property `Secure='yes'`

Comment: @BrianSutherland this should be an answer...solved the problem for me